# Orchard Content Per user

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm making a web project where the Administrators will be able to create a content item for specific new user . so i want that the user sees only the content specified by the administrator .

so whenever the user log in , will only sees the content (menu , layout ..) specified by the administrator .

the way i'm trying to achieve this is :

-The administrator set the owner of the content item to the targeted user .

-using `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler` i specify the content using the current userId

is there anyway to get the content by userId ? or is there any other good way to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all content items with a specific owner you can do:

```
var userId = ...; //
_contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Published)
  .Where<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.OwnerId == userId)
  .List();
```

Check a particular content item for the owner:

```
var ownerId = contentItem.As<CommonPart>.Owner.Id;
```

You can access the current user by injecting IOrchardServices

```
var currentUserId = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser.Id;
```

**EDIT:**

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but if you want a single url to return a different content item depending on the user I'd suggest creating a new controller with an action method that retrieves the users content item and displays that. You can refer to the Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController.cs class for an example of how to render a content item from a controller.

If you have many content items that need to be rendered with a different version for each user it is a little more complex. A simple solution could be to create a content type and attach a content picker field called UserContent. This content type would act as the master that would render a specific item for the user. The admin would create child items, set the owner to the specified user and add the child item to the masters content picker field (UserContent). We could then write an alternate display shape for UserContent (a little hacky I know, the better - but slightly more work - way would be to create a new driver for ContentPickerField. So drop a file called `Fields.ContentPicker-UserContent` into your module's View folder and you can have something like the following inside:

```
@{
  var userId = WorkContext.CurrentUser.Id;
  var field = (ContentPickerField)Model.ContentField;
  var contentItem = field.ContentItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.As<CommonPart>().Owner.Id == userId);
}

@if(contentItem != null) {
  <div>
    @Display(contentItem.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem, "Detail"))
  </div>
}
```

Code written in notepad so may not compile...

Comment: Thanks ! , but how can i render the user Content item instead ?

Comment: thank you for your reply , What i need more specifically is to create a layout which contains some contents and assign it to a specific user

Comment: You'll need to create a custom layout element then. There are many examples in the orchard source code. Have a look at the orchard.Layouts module